# Input Audio as a Stream in CF 3.5

Tags: .net, audio, input, inputstream, audio-streaming

I googled around and coulnd't really find an answer.

**How do I open an audio input device** (namely a microphone) **as a stream** (preferably) **on a CE/WinMobile device using Compact Framework?**

I looked at WindowsMobile.DirectX, at various classes that contained Audio in their name and nothing seemed to do the trick.

What I want to do is basically to stream the audio input over the network to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answer for "trying to do something with the CF and can't" is OpenNetCF.

Here's the [page for WaveAudio](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/f3fc3169-4143-54bc-1594-186da1fb01c2.htm) which includes a Recorder class with a RecordFor method that records to a stream for a given number of seconds.  It's not quite ideal for your purposes, but really close.  The OpenNetCF folk tend to be pretty responsive to requests.